# Ruby on Rails: Cant figure out why my jQuery-ui autocomplete isn't working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, search, autocomplete

I just followed a youtube tutorial on adding a jQuery-ui autocomplete feature to my search field. This is the link to the tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iMz8HmrQ350.

For some reason it is not working, despite going over the tutorial and rechecking syntax constantly. I'm NOT getting any errors when I reload the web browser, however, nothing appears as a drop down menu as I type in the search field. Interestingly though, if I use an array for sample data, it works (the drop down menu appears with suggestions using the sample array data). But when I try to link it to my database of posts, it no longer works. I have shown example code for both ways below.

My code is below - any help is much appreciated i've been trying to add this feature for a while attempting countless tutorials and methods. It's getting annoying haha.

I am new to coding and have taught myself thus far. Please let me know if any other files are required.

PS. I'm currently using elastic search and search kick for a simple search. Could that possibly have anything to do with the autocomplete feature not working? I'm also using the gem: "gem 'query-ui-rails'" in my gem file incase that is important to know.

posts.coffee

```
jQuery ->
$('#search').autocomplete
    source: "/search_suggestions"
```

search_suggestions_controller.rb

```
class SearchSuggestionsController < ApplicationController

    def index
        render json: SearchSuggestion.terms_for(params[:term])
    end
end
```

IF I USE AN ARRAY AS SAMPLE DATA, IT WORKS - EXAMPLE:

```
 class SearchSuggestionsController < ApplicationController

     def index
        render json: %w[test test1]
     end
 end
```

MODEL: search_suggestion.rb

```
class SearchSuggestion < ApplicationRecord

    attr_accessible :popularity, :term

    def self.terms_for(prefix)
        suggestions = where("term like ?", "#{prefix}_%")
        suggestions.order("popularity desc").limit(10).pluck(:term)
    end

    def self.index_posts
        Post.find_each do |post|
            index_term(post.title)
            post.title.split.each { |t| index_term(t) }
        end
    end

    def self.index_term(term)
        where(term: term.downcase).first_or_initialize.tap do |suggestion|
            suggestion.increment! :popularity
        end
    end
end
```

TASK FILE: search_suggestions.rake

```
 namespace :search_suggestions do 
     desc "Generate search suggestions from posts"
     task :index => :environment do
         SearchSuggestion.index_posts
     end
end
```

Comment: anyone??? pleaaases

Answer (score 0):

If it works with your array stub, then it means your JS is probably working, and there is something funky going on in your controller / model.

Have you checked the request jquery makes to your browser ? and the response ?

I'm not sure how your data is structured, but

`suggestions = where("term like ?", "#{prefix}_%")`

looks little bit fishy.

A few points to check :

1. Check the request from developer console in your browser. Check if the term param is sent correctly, and if there is anything in the response payload (the way you desribe looks like response comes empty)
2. Use pry in your controller / model, check the params coming in, and the result of the query `suggestions = where("term like ?", "#{prefix}_%")`
3. Check if the rake task actually worked (you ran the rake task right ?). And if your terms have been properly populated. (Something like `SearchSuggestion.all` in the console.)